# problem in topology. looking for conditions under which given topology is discrete?

Tags: general-topology

Let $\tau$ be the topology on $\mathbb{R}$ for which the intervals $[a, b), -\infty < a< b < \infty$, form a base. Let $\sigma$ be a topology on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\sigma \supseteq \tau$. Then,

a) either $\sigma = \tau $ or $\sigma$ is discrete topology.

b) if, moreover , the map $x \to -x$ is continuous from $\sigma$, then $\sigma$ is discrete topology.

c)  if, moreover , the map $x \to -x$ is a homeomorphism for $\sigma$, then $\sigma$ is discrete topology.

d)  if, moreover , the map $x \to |x|$ is homeomorphism for $\sigma$, then $\sigma$ is discrete topology.

How to proceed forward? i have no idea. plz help me

Comment: $[a, b)$ or $(a, b)$ ?

Comment: @Tom Collinge it is $[a, b)$.

Comment: Statement (a) is false. Let $\mathscr{B}$ consist of the intervals $[a,b)$ with $a<b$ and the set $\{0\}$. Show that $\mathscr{B}$ is a base for a non-discrete topology $\sigma$ on $\Bbb R$ such that $\sigma\supsetneqq\tau$.

Comment: i got (b) true as i able to prove singeltons are open.

Comment: @kapil: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @ Brian M. Scott (c) also holds as (b) holds.

Comment: If $x\mapsto-x$ is continuous then also intervals like $(a,b]$ are open (as preimages of open sets w.r.t. a continuous function). Now write singletons as a finite intersection of two open sets.

Comment: @ Brian M. Scott for (a) is it enough to prove any singleton which is not open?

Comment: @ Brian M. Scott can you give a proof or any hint of your statement for (a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer concerning a) inspired by the comment of Brian.

Observe that $\mathcal B:=\{[a,b)\mid a,b\in\mathbb R\wedge a<b\}$ has the following properties:

- If $B_1,B_2\in\mathcal B$ then $B_1\cap B_2$ can be written as an (eventual empty) union of elements of $\mathcal B$.
- $\mathbb R$ can be written as a union of elements of $\mathcal B$.

That means that $\mathcal B$ is a [base of a topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)#Definition_and_basic_properties) $\tau$ on $\mathbb R$. The elements of $\tau$ are the subsets of $\mathbb R$ that can be written as an (eventual empty) union of elements of $\mathcal B$.

If $x\in U\in\tau$ then $a,b\in\mathbb R$ exist with $x\in[a,b)\subseteq U$. This shows that $U\neq\{x\}$ and we conclude $\{x\}\notin\tau$ for every $x\in\mathbb R$.

Let $\mathcal B':=\mathcal B\cup\{\{0\}\}$ and observe that it also has the two properties mentioned above, so that $\sigma$ is a topology if it is the collection of (eventual empty) unions of elements of $\mathcal B'$. From $\mathcal B\subset\mathcal B'$ it follows that $\tau\subseteq\sigma$ and from $\{0\}\in\sigma-\tau$ it follows that the inclusion is proper. As above we deduce that $\{x\}\notin\sigma$ for every $x\in\mathbb R-\{0\}$. That means that $\sigma$ is not discrete.

Comment: Thanks, u made it look easy,